# Thumb drive not showing up in finder

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I recently got a 64GB thumb drive and tried to install macOS Big Sur on it however after my computer restarted it showed an error that said something along the lines of "the process couldn't be completed" I don't remember exactly. Everything else on my computer is fine except the thumb drive doesn't show up anywhere. Not in disk utility, and not in the output of `diskutil list`.
Any ideas as what could have gone wrong?

Comment: It’s a hunch but when you connect the device, does activity monitor show a new `fsck` process started? Also, in [Disk Utility do you show all devices](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/view-all-devices-or-only-volumes-dskud6b39edb/mac)

Comment: No,  I don't see any 'fsck' but  however a 'diskarbitrand' does appear. Yes, Disk utility is set to 'show all devices'.

Comment: Does the stick appear in the list of USB devices in System Information?

Comment: No it doesn't, but now it shows up in "diskutil list". It, however doesn't seem to be mounted. Is there a way to do that from terminal?